# PSTricks and documentclass

Tags: pstricks, document-classes

I have a problem using PSTricks for `elsevier` journal.

As you may know, preprints and review versions of papers usually use a different `documentclass` in LaTeX than the one used for the final version of the paper.

The problem is that I wrote my paper and all figures are done with PSTricks, but when I change the `documentclass` of the final version to generate the `pdf`, all pictures change size and the elements of each `pspicture` is messed up.

How can I solve this issue??

Comment: Can you post a compilable example with 1 figure that shows the problem?  You also need to tell us which Elsevier document class causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in `\documentclass`, but in the fact that PSTricks do not work with `pdftex`.   Use `latex->dvips->ps2dpf` route instead.

By the way, when submitting a paper to an Elsevier journal, it is better to prepare graphics separately and submit it as EPS files (this can be done with PSTricks).  You never know what do they use in their system.

Comment: While this may be true, it doesn't seem to follow from what @Juan has posted so far, since he clearly can compile his document with the non-Elsevier class. Is the Elsevier submission process automated, and only uses pdflatex?

Comment: Elsevier process is indeed automated.  I do not know what do they use internally, but eps graphics is processed fine.

Comment: @AlanMunn Anyway, I've updated my answer.  I think Elsevier does not expect the graphics to be generated during LaTeX run.

Comment: If the Elsevier system accepts EPS files, it's likely to be  *not* using `pdflatex`, which also fits with @Juan's description: his document compiles, but the images are the wrong size.

Comment: @AlanMunn  Not necessary: my current pdflatex happily uses eps files in \includegraphics. Since TL2011 one of the graphics rules is to transparently call repstopdf behind the scenes.